# Angularjs cascading dropdowns

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I need to use angular service to create cascading drop-downs.The commented code I created for testing purpose and it is working fine. I need to create two services to call two methods from the MVC controller : GetCompanies() and GetDocTypes()
My questions are: Is my first service correct and how can I call the services from the controller?
Thank you.

```
/// <reference path="angular.js" />
//var myApp = angular
//    .module("myApp", [])
//    .controller("companyController", function ($scope, $http) {

//    $http.post('CurrentSettings/GetCompanies')
//        .then(function (response) {
//            var response = $.parseJSON(response.data);
//            $scope.currentSettings = response;
//        });
//    });

var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.service('getCompanies', function () {
$http.post('CurrentSettings/GetCompanies')
.then(function (response) {
    var response = $.parseJSON(response.data);
    $scope.currentSettings = response;
    });
});

myApp.controller("companyController", function ($scope, getCompanies,   $http) {
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your service is two-fold:

Firstly, there is no way to call the service. You injected it fine, but now what? Think of your service as an API; it's no good just having a reference to it somewhere, you need to be able to use it. I would change to the following:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);    
myApp.service('getCompanies', ["$http", function($http) {
  this.currentSettings = "Hello";
  $http.post('CurrentSettings/GetCompanies')
    .then(function(response) {
      var response = $.parseJSON(response.data);
      this.currentSettings = response;
    });    
}]);

myApp.controller("companyController", ["$scope", "getCompanies", 
function($scope, getCompanies) {
  $scope.currentSettings = getCompanies.currentSettings;
}]);
```

Note a few things:

1. You need to explicitly inject $http into your service.
2. I specify the names of the services that I'm injecting as part of an array that includes the function. This actually allows you to name the parameters anything you want, and is considered a best practice.
3. The service doesn't use $scope directly. Instead, it makes a field available to clients of the service. That client (the controller in this case) can then do with the value whatever it wants, including assigning it to a $scope field.
4. The controller reads this field from the service. It could also call any functions you specified - making the service an API, as I mentioned before.

The second problem is one of timing. Notice that I used the super-original value of "Hello" to initialize the service field.

*The value you receive from the service will depend on whether or not the controller reads the value after your call to the MVC controller returns.*

To fix this, the service could expose a second field to indicate that the company list is fully loaded, but that really shifts the problem around instead of fixing it.

What you need is a function that returns a promise. If the value has already been loaded, the promise resolves immediately. If not, it returns a promise that will return once the $http call is done.

Here is the modified code:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.service('companiesService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
  var currentSettings = null;

  this.getList = function() {
    var def = $q.defer()
    if (currentSettings) {
      def.resolve(currentSettings);
    } else {
      $http.get('CurrentSettings/GetCompanies')
        .then(function(response) {
          var response = response.data;
          currentSettings = response;
          def.resolve(currentSettings);
        });
    }
    return def.promise;
  }
}]);

myApp.controller('companyController', ['$scope', 'companiesService',
  function($scope, companiesService) {
    $scope.currentSettings = '';
    companiesService.getList().then(function(value) {
      $scope.currentSettings = value;
    });
  }
]);
```

It becomes a bit more complicated because you have to use promises, but these are the things to note:

1. I changed the name of the service to make it more generic. It can now offer a number of company-related features.
2. currentSettings is no longer added to this on the service, but instead becomes a normal (private) variable. The calling code can only read it by calling the getList function.
3. getList returns a promise. The promise is resolved immediately if currentSettings has been assigned. If not, it only resolves once the value is received from the web service.
4. The controller calls getList and assigns the value to the $scope field in the then function.

Comment: Thank you . I implemented your code and everything works perfect. I created another service. How can I pass the selected value from the first service(drop-down) to the second service(drop-down) to be able to filter the second drop-down. I am using two services in two separate controls.

Comment: Same concept. The two services should not have direct knowledge of one another, since you are actually filtering service 2 from the UI. I would suggest service 2 should expose a function that takes a parameter to filter with. Once the user selects from the company dropdown, call this function on service 2.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if you found it helpful.